# NodeJS + MongoDb Multiply request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Привет всем, работаю над проектом новостного портала с парсингом новостей с различных сайтов, Стек NodeJs + Express + MongoDb + ReactJS.

Мне кажется что у меня есть проблема в запросах в базу для главной страницы нужно сделать более 7 запросов, чтоб вытащить ленту новостей, 5 последних новостей в 4 различных категории, видеозаписи и популярные новости по просмотрам и тд.

Первый вариант думаю глупый

```
news.find({}, {....}).toArray(function(err, data) { 
    var NewsArray = data;
    politics.find({}, {....}).toArray(function(err, data) { 
      var politicsArray = data;
      ..../ Тут еще куча запросов, а уже в конце render со всеми переменными. 
    }

});
```

Второй вариант даже не знаю может тоже не правильный.

```
 var _timer = 0,
     newsArray,
     politicsArray;


 news.find({}, {....}).toArray(function(err, data) { 
    newsArray = data;
    _timer++;
 })

 politics.find({}, {....}).toArray(function(err, data) { 
    politicsArray = data;
    _timer++;
 })
```

Еще 6 запросов....

```
renderToPage();

function renderToPage(){
   if(_timer != 8(in example)){
       setTimeout(render, 100)
   } else {
       res.render(".....", {})
   }
}
```

Прошу помочь нормально сформировать запросы чтоб это было красиво и не грузило сервер, а то при двух запросах один выбирает категории, а второй новости 50 штук с лимитом. Уже DomContentLoaded 2,3 sec

Comment: Попробуйте сократить количество запрашиваемых данных.
`b.collection.find({дата больше заданной},{только нужные поля}).sort({по свежести}).limit(например 5 последних, а не все от сотворения мира)`

Comment: Спасибо, реализовал через async

Comment: Владимир, опубликуйте тогда свое решение, вероятно, я даже проголосую за него)